# Compile Crystal Reports into an exe

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, crystal-reports

I've recently made the switch from the Data Report to Crystal Reports 10. I've rewritten  the reports our software uses and they are working fine in a nominal reports location.

I have heard that Crystal Reports can be compiled into a single executable file which can be called through vb.net, rather than loading the report from a location.

Has anyone had any experience of this who can perhaps help?

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal Report itself can be compiled in with the applications executable, but I believe the client computer still requires the Crystal Reports runtime be installed as a prerequisite.

Comment: Well i am interested in crystal report in application executable as that will make my reports un-editable by external users. About runtime files i dont mind installing in clients

Comment: I think they are compiled in by default where you'd need to change the "Build Action" to "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy Always" in the properties of the report if you wanted the report to be separate. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible, I created a view of the data I need then create a crystal report form the view table to populate your report.

Comment: Could you please add more details about your solution?